# What is this climbing plant with blue flowers?

Tags: identification, vines

I bought this astonishing, climbing plant months ago, but I wasn't able to identify it.

Here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: Beautiful flower, btw! The color on it is fantastic.

Comment: @Paulster2 One day at the morning I woke up and I saw it's beauty, I was shocked by how vivid it is. I really love this plant, I bought it without knowing it has this magnificent flower structure. Just WOW! I feel lucky and happy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks like a [*clitoria ternata*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitoria_ternatea). The wiki page says:

> Clitoria ternatea, common names including *butterfly pea, blue pea, Cordofan pea* and *Asian pigeonwings*, is a plant species belonging to the Fabaceae family. The flowers of this vine have the shape of human female genitals, hence the Latin name of the genus "Clitoria", from "clitoris".

[image: Image pulled from fleur-des-tropiques.com]

Answer (score 4):

This is called Gokarn in India. It is used for floral worship in some temples on Saturday.